# Creating a letter guessing game for school assignment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

SO I have been stuck on this exercise for way too long and not sure what it is I am doing wrong. I am having a difficult time with arrays and incorporating loops with them.

The assignment is to put 10 letters inside an array and have the user guess at least one letter right. After 3 tries tell the user they have lost and terminate the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Exercise 5</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles5.css"/>
</head>



<body>
  <!--E X C E R S I S E 5 !-->
  <section id="allContent">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="bar1"></div><div id="bar2"></div>
      <h1 id="excersize">E x c e r c i c e &ensp;5</h1>
      <div id="titleBox">
        <p id="titlePRG">Enter five words</p>
      </div>
      <input type="text"   id="textField">
      <form>
        <input type="button" value="Enter" class="button" onclick="getValue()">   
      </form>
      <div id="valueReturned">
        <p id="returnText"><p>
        </div>
        <a href="index6.html"><h3> Next Exercise </h3></a>
      </div>
      <img src ="blank-laptop-png-transparent-pictures-free-icons-graphic-transparent-library-laptop-png-4042_3027.png" alt="laptopGraphic">
  </section>
    <!--E N D   O F   E X C E R c I c E 5 !-->


            <!-- S C R I P T I N G !-->
            <script>
        function getValue(){
          var input = document.getElementById("textField").value;
          var letters  =  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"] ;
          var a = letters.indexOf(input);


          for(var attempts = 0; attempts < 3; attempts++){

            if(input == ""){
            document.getElementById("valueReturned").innerHTML = "No input!";
            }else if( a >= 0){
              document.getElementById("valueReturned").innerHTML = "You guessed right!";

             break;

            } else if(input != a && attempts == 0){
              document.getElementById("valueReturned").innerHTML = "Two tries left!";
            }else if(input != a && attempts == 1){
              document.getElementById("valueReturned").innerHTML = "One more try!";
            }else if(input != a && attempts == 2){
              document.getElementById("valueReturned").innerHTML = "That was your last try! Get lost!";
            }

            }

           }// end of function
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

So If the user guesses right, I want the code to stop running or the loop rather.
If the guess is wrong on the first attempt then it should display a message "Two tries left!"
If the guess is wrong on the second attempt then it should display a message "One try left!"
And so on...

I didn't close off my conditions with an else statement for now, not sure if its needed.
Is my For loop not set up right?
Are my if, else if conditions not right?

I desperately need your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're iterating over the 3 attempts *for every attempt*.

You need to iterate globally, for all attempts.

In other words, track the attempts outside of the function, otherwise each time the function is called you're resetting attempts to 3 - it will never go down.

Here's my refactoring of your code, which also fixes a few other things and optimises it.

```
(() => {
    let attempts = 3,
        input_el = document.getElementById('textField'),
        result_el = document.getElementById('valueReturned');
    window.getValue = () => {
        let input = input_el.value,
        letters  =  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
        correct = letters.includes(input),
        msg;

        if (!attempts)
            msg = 'No attempts left!';
        else if (!input)
            msg = "No input!";
        else if(!correct) {
            attempts--;
            switch (attempts) {
                case 2:
                    msg = 'Two tries left!'
                    break;
                case 1:
                    msg = 'One more try!';
                    break;
                case 0:
                    msg = 'That was your last try! Get lost!';
                    break;
            }
        } else
            msg = 'You guessed right!';

        result_el.innerHTML = msg;

    }
})();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aerz6kpt/)

Some points of note:

- Name your variables indicatively
- Separate your JS from your HTML - put it in dedicated `.js` files.
- Use `let` over `var` these days
- Consider centralised event handling rather than inline JS via `onclick` attributes. This would also mean we don't have to declare a global function on `window` for your `onclick` to reference.
- We wrap the whole thing in an IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression) to prevent pollution of the global namespace.
- Think about what *doesn't* need to be duplicated each time your event fires. We don't need to fetch from the DOM the references to the same elements each time - let's do that outside the function.
- `array.includes(val)` is equivalent to `array.indexOf(val) !== -1`.
- I've also made it impossible for users to have more than 3 attempts.

Comment: Just saw this now and I am going to make some changes. I am a little frustrated cause I do attend a private school and the program is condensed, we are learning JavaScript in a very short time and the theory they provide to us is missing a lot of stuff. The content is old, they provide tutorial videos from 2011, thus the reason you might see me using things that are outdated, I do see "let" used much more than var. Even more frustrating is I got more answers from you in this post than I did from the teacher the past 2 days, communicating via messaging because of the virus is proving difficult

Comment: @gears244 Unfortunately it's common for web development teaching to rely on old standards/software. I've interviewed people still being taught to create sites in Adobe Dreamweaver! If you're serious about JavaScript I'd strongly advise you to pick it up yourself and just use the classes as a top-up. A book like David Flanagan's JavaScript: Tthe Definitive Guide will take you from noob to ninja, if you have the write mind for programming.

Answer (score 1):

let's walk through your logic

```
<script>
        function getValue(){
          var input = document.getElementById("textField").value;
          var letters  =  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"] ;
          var a = letters.indexOf(input);
```

in this bit, you opened a script tag and declared a function `getValue`.
Then you grab the input from the html element with id `"textField"`, initialize an array `letters` with 10 letters, then search `letters` for `input`, returning its index. However, this causes the input to be read only once. Then it will execute your for loop for three iterations, creating a potentially unwanted error.

Think of it this way,

Your function needs to be started somewhere. By its embedding in the html, it will occur `onclick()` for a button under the input. this means that each time the function is called, *the input is read once and the loop runs three times **on the same input***. I would start by creating a variable **outside of your `getValue` function**--we'll call it `attempts`--which will allow us to update the variable each time the function is run. Then get rid of the for loop, and use conditional branching, e.g.

```
var attempts = 0;
function getValue(){
  var input = document.getElementById("textField").value;
  var letters  =  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"] ;
  var a = letters.indexOf(input);
  if (attempts < 3) {
    // check if input is right
    if (input != "" && a != -1) {
       alert("success");
    }
    attempts += 1;
  }
// no else statement needed to terminate the program
// simply don't handle occurrences of attempts greater than  3
}
```

pls comment anything you're unsure of

Comment: can you use a while loop, or a do-while loop?

Comment: Its entirely up to me, my teacher said he wants us to limit the attempts using loops, he said it can be done with a for loop but i dont see how. Do while seemed the easiest and I practically had it coded and decided to try for a For. Main problem I had was I was declaring my variable locally and my if else conditions are all jumbled. I always seem to be slightly dyslexic when branching my conditions.My teacher really is pushing that we use loops though

Comment: @gears244 yeah using loops is pivotal in handling non-trivial amounts of data input. If you were to use a for loop, I can really only see it working with an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener), which might be beyond the scope of your material. However, I am pretty bad at logic so maybe you don't need the event listener for a particular solution